# How to reverse array at same place in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

i would like to ask for help if any of you have time. trying to write a code which take user input, then save entered numbers to array and then trying to reverse it. everything is working fine but last line "reversed number of array is" compiles twice, first it shows revesred numbers and then shows original cant find out what is wrong with it. any ideas?
p.s goal is to reveres number at same place. without additioanl array, or variable;
 same aproach without user input works fine.

```
  public class ReverseUserIputArray {
public static void main(String[]args){
    int anArray;
    Scanner inArray = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter how many elements to save in array");
    int elements = inArray.nextInt();
    System.out.println("you want to have  " + elements + " element");
    int[] array = new int[elements];
    if(elements==0 || array.length <=1){
        System.out.println("compile again");
    }
    for(int i=0; i<elements;i++){
        System.out.println("index " + i);
        array[i] = inArray.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println("original array is " + Arrays.toString(array));
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        anArray = array[i];
        array[i] = array[array.length - 1 - i];
        array[array.length - 1 - i] = anArray;
        System.out.println("reversed number of array is " + Arrays.toString(array));
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Move the println after the loop.

Comment: Elliot does not work, after moving println outside of loop it doesnt reverse at all

Comment: Only loop to `i * 2 < array.length`, reversing the second half with the first puts everything back.

Comment: thanks mate it works now, but can you explain what happaned?

Comment: just try it with an example say  `a [1 2 3]`, length of array `3`. So if `2*i<3`,  i =1 a[0]<-->a[2]  ==> [3 2 1] ... but if you continue for  i=2 a[2]<-->a[0] ==> a [1 2 3]...

Comment: i'm puting any number now to i*2<array.lenght and it still works. can not understand why

Comment: It's the same as `i < array.length / 2`